# Entity Framework how to filter twice

Tags: entity-framework

I have Tags,Products,and Categories that are related to each other.  Products can have many tags and Products can have many categories.

Can someone show me what the syntax might look like if I wanted to get all products for a specific tag **and** a specific category?

P.S I'm asking this from my phone. If someone doesn't mind editing my post to be better formatted, feel free and then delete this P.S note.

Answer (score 4):

If you have tagId and categoryId, Something like this should work for you:

```
db.Products
    .Where(pr => 
         pr.Categories.Any(c => c.Id == categoryId) 
         && pr.Tags.Any(t => t.Id == tagId))
    .ToList()
```

This query will filter all products which are part of the specific category and the specific tag.